# recording scripts with Jmeter for non DWR AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, jmeter

The recording controller does not show the AJAX calls which are mapped with *.do style calls. I have used it in the include pattern but it still does not show under the recording controller.

Any help please.

Comment: Show your include pattern in question

Comment: .*\.do.* to include params on the query string if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove include pattern in exclude pattern remove them all and click on add Suggested Excludes.

Comment: I didn't quite catch that. You are asking me to remove the include pattern by putting it in the exclude pattern?

Comment: No remove include and exclude patterns to ser if there s an error in them